# RTCPeerConnection connection state fail between browser and Django Server

Tags: python, django-channels, mediastream, rtcpeerconnection, aiortc

I am using aortic to build RTCPeerConnection with the browser and the server using Django.

the server can receive offer from the browser and the browser can receive answer from the server

however, from the server side:

```
@aioConnection.on("connectionstatechange")
async def on_connectionstatechange():
    print("Connection state is %s" % aioConnection.connectionState)

@aioConnection.on("track")
def on_track(track):
    print("======= received track: ", track, flush=True)
            if track.kind == "video":
        newTrack = VideoStreamTrack(track)
        aioConnection.addTrack(newTrack)
```

the log show that:

```
Oct  5 06:00:43 ip-172-31-30-121 gunicorn[2999]: /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiortc/rtcdtlstransport.py:186: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: This version of cryptography contains a temporary pyOpenSSL fallback path. Upgrade pyOpenSSL now.
Oct  5 06:00:43 ip-172-31-30-121 gunicorn[2999]:   value=certificate_digest(self._cert._x509),  # type: ignore
Oct  5 06:00:43 ip-172-31-30-121 gunicorn[2999]: ======= received track:  <aiortc.rtcrtpreceiver.RemoteStreamTrack object at 0x7efde9842ec0>
Oct  5 06:00:43 ip-172-31-30-121 gunicorn[2999]: Connection 1 state is connecting
Oct  5 06:01:15 ip-172-31-30-121 gunicorn[2999]: Connection 1 state is failed
Oct  5 06:01:15 ip-172-31-30-121 gunicorn[2999]: Connection 1 state is closed
```

And in the browser side (javascript),

```
        aioConnection.addEventListener('track', function (evt) {
            console.log("receive server video");
            console.log(evt.streams[0])
    document.getElementById(“video”).srcObject = evt.streams[0];
        });
```

the console successfully log the "receive server video" and the Mediastream
However, no video is showing and the RTCPeerConnection is broken.

I also saw an error suggesting a connection lost has occurred (as shown from the log below).

```
Task exception was never retrieved
<Task finished name='Task-82' coro=<TurnClientMixin.delete() done, defined at /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aioice/turn.py:147> exception=InvalidStateError('invalid state')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aioice/turn.py", line 167, in delete
self.receiver.connection_lost(None)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aioice/ice.py", line 175, in connection_lost
self.__closed.set_result(True)
asyncio.exceptions.InvalidStateError: invalid state
```

note: when I run the code in localhost and in some WiFi networks, there is no such problem, the connection state is connected. But in some WiFi network and 4G mobile data, I cannot build the PeerConnection and have the above problem.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.